# kendoui move grid to other div

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

What I'm trying to do sounds easy, but I can not get it working. I have a razor-built kendo ui grid. Now once the whole page is rendered I want to move that grid to another div on the same page. I thought it would be easy when I wrap a `div` around the grid ("lgc_list_container") and use `JQuery` to move that div into the other one:

1- After the page is loaded (AutoBind is set to false)

(tried to add images but since I'm new here, thats not possible so i'll try to describe)
The grid is correctly loaded with no data in it.

2- I move the grid to the other div a bit lower

```
$('#lgc_list_container').detach().appendTo('#anotherContainer')
```

3- Moved:

The empty grid is moved, no problem so far.

4- I invoke the datasource read()

```
$("#person_lgc_list").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read()
```

5- The result :

The rows are not set in the grid but rendered below the grid!!

Anyone any sugestions other than quit razor and use the kendo js api? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much easier than that. There is no need for detaching or for re-reading the dataSource.

If we consider that the HTML is something like:

```
<div id="container1">
    <div id="grid"></div>
</div>

<div id="container2"></div>
```

Where our `grid` is initially wrapped by a `div` which `id` is *container1* and we want to move it to *container2*. What we do is getting the HTML for the `grid` and place it inside `container2`.

Something like:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
$("#container2").html(grid.element);
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/kxsfsamu/